# How to set Default value in autocomplete implemented textbox?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

I have a textbox implemented with autocomplete. Here is it.

```
<input id="txtcity" />
$("#txtcity").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("CityLookup", "PatientDemographic", "")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
      data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
      success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
          return { label: item.Text, value: item.Text, id: item.Value }
        }))
      }
    })
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
    $("#CityCode").val(ui.item.id);
  },
  open: function () {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
  },
  close: function () {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
  }
});
```

**This returns three results, let's say "Apple", "Banana", "Cabbage". How do I set a default value to "Banana" while rendering ? i.e, text="banana" value="2"?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can set the value like this after initializing Autocomplete:

```
$( "#txtcity" ).autocomplete({
  // do whatever
}).val('Banana').data('autocomplete')._trigger('select');
```

Updated Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/55jhx/1/

Comment: It displays the text in the textbox, but the value is null. Text='Banana', value= '2'. In the database , the value field remains null.

Comment: Can you try adding .trigger('select') at the end?

Comment: I am not very good at that. can you please guide me to complete that ?

Comment: not working Ed. Still the value field is null. If i erase the value in textbox and type "b" and select "banana" i am getting the value "2" in db field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31637/discussion-between-codebrain-and-edward)

Answer (score 3):

Change your following line

```
 $('#txtcity').val() = item.value;
```

to

```
 $('#txtcity').val(item.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the click for the first element in the `ul` to fire the select for autocomplete:

```
$("ul.ui-autocomplete li").first().trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed this using __response() method. Hope this help to anyone looking for the solution.

```
$( 'selector' ).autocomplete( 'instance' ).__response = function(a) {
    let defaultValue = {
        label : 'Not found',
        value : null
    }
    if( a.length === 0 ) {
        a.push( $instance.elements.defaultValue ); 
    } else {
        a.unshift( $instance.elements.defaultValue ); 
    }
    a && (a = this._normalize(a)), this._trigger("response", null, {
        content: a
    }), !this.options.disabled && a && a.length && !this.cancelSearch ? (this._suggest(a), this._trigger("open")) : this._close();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
$( "#txtcity" ).autocomplete({
  // do whatever
}).val('Banana').data('autocomplete')._trigger('select');
```

and it doesn't work as expected. it automatically selects the value, but this results as `null`.

So I simply tried:

```
$( "#txtcity" ).autocomplete({
  // do whatever
}).val('Banana')
```

and this selects the value and it isn't `null`.